# Keras model returns different values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, precision

To play with data, I have trained a linear regression with Keras+TensorFlow, and compared the first prediction computed in 3 different ways:

1. I got the weights from the model, and just used the linear regression formula `p = w*X0 + b`
2. I got predictions using the `model.predict(X)` method of Keras for the whole data array `X` and then took only the first element of it
3. I got prediction using the same method only for the first row of features `X0` (the first sample)

In theory, all those methods should produce the very same value. However, in practice I do get values that are a bit different.

[image: Different values]

This difference is not that big, but still I wonder why is that the case, only due to float precision in python?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the fact that matrix multiplications and convolutions are implemented in a way which is non-deterministic (if you change the batch size you change the order in which multiply-adds happen and since floating point numbers are not associative you get slightly different results).